# PHP mcrypt error, unsuccessful decryption

Tags: php, cryptography

The code below does not decrypt the plaintext correctly. Does anyone know why the decrypt will not give me the correct plain text?

```
<?php

$key = "ShHhd8a08JhJiho98ayslcjh";
$plaintext = "Let us meet at 9 o'clock at the secret place.";
$cyphertext = "arTdPqWOg6VppOqUD6mGITjb24+x5vJjfAufNQ4DN7rVEtpDmhFnMVM+W/WFlksR";


$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $cyphertext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

echo base64_encode($encrypted)."</br>";
echo base64_encode($decrypted)."</br>";
?>
```

Comment: Instead of `echo base64_encode($decrypted)`, why don't you.. echo the `$decrypted`?

Comment: I also needed to echo $decrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cyphertext looks to be base64-encoded already, so you're comparing apples/oranges. Assuming your `$cyphertext` is correctly generated in the first place, you'd have to compare

```
$cyphertext == base64_encode($encrypted)
```

to get a valid comparison, or

```
base64_decode($cyphertext) == $encrypted
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was looking at it for fifteen minutes completely dumbfounded.